# Why won't append row work with array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, append

I am trying to insert a row to the bottom of a sheet, but instead of my values I see text similar to what happens when you try to print an array in Java. I checked to see if the array is made correctly with logger and it has the values I want.

```
var name = e.range.getRow() + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var array = e.range.getValues().concat(name);
Logger.log(array.toString());
masterSheet.appendRow(array);
```

`array` contains a timestamp, string1, string2, and finally the name I concatenated. Instead I get something like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@7dch7145`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem with your use of `getValues()` which returns a two-dimensional array and needs to be accessed as such.

[GAS API Reference: getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

> Return
>
> Object[][] — a two-dimensional array of values

I believe this edit to setting your `var array` should do the trick, assuming your data range is for a single row (index 0 will be the first row, otherwise just change the index to the row you want):

```
var array = e.range.getValues()[0].concat(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `appendRow()` is looking for array[] not array[][].

If you attempt to append:

```
var array = [[1,2,3],"some string"]
```

It will show up as the following as it is trying to get the entire contents of the first position of the array in a single cell. It does this by returning a string of the array object which turns out to be the native code identifier.

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@32dba1e2 |  some string
```

You can append the contents of array by appending its individual members such as

```
ss.appendRow(array[0])
```

Would append

```
1 | 2 | 3
```